# Alternate way to perform If operation based on the request

Tags: java, spring-boot, logic

The class

```
public class Details {
      private String name;
      private String id;
      //more attributes
}
```

I have a method which takes the http request and write an xml file based on the attribute the request wants (basically exporting specific fields that user wants).

Http Request body,

```
{
  "isNameRequired": true,
  "isIdRequired": true,
  "isAttrRequired": false
  // and other params to for filtering
}
```

Eg -> if the request wants only 'name' and 'id' values, the request will have booleans such as isNameRequired and IsIdRequired.
Based on this booleans my condition would look like

```
if (isNameRequired) {
   // write name on file
}
if (isIdRequired) {
   // write id on file
}
```

This is just an example. The actual attributes I want to write is more than 50 and I'm having that many booleans and multiple if checks to write.
Note : The entire process can happen n number of times.

There is list of Details (size > 100)  which I need to loop through and write a xml based on users request.

If the user only needs name and id field, my xml should look like

```
<info>
  <detail1>
    <name>somename</name>
    <id>someid</id>
  </detail1>
  <detail2>
    <name>somename</name>
    <id>someid</id>
  </detail2>
</info>
```

like wise, if the request needs only name,

```
<info>
  <detail1>
    <name>somename</name>
  </detail1>
  <detail2>
    <name>somename</name>
  </detail2>
</info>
```

My question is, is this approach correct or is there a better way to handle this situation?

Comment: You have provided too little information so that an accurate answer is not possible. There are certainly other approaches, such as storing only the required fields in a list, or a map with true and false as keys, and a list of required and non-required attributes as vlues... Please give a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Eritrean I've editied the question, hope this is clear and thanks for responding

Comment: How does your request look like?

Comment: Updated the question with the request body, thanks @Eritrean

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your code but you could have some form of request handler that operates on a single requested element (e.g. "name"). If that fits your needs you could maintain a map of those handlers, get the ones you need and use them.

I'll add a simple example and assume your requests contain a number of strings for what's needed (if it's different I'll leave the conversion to you :) ):

```
interface RequestedElementHandler {
   String getHandledElementName();
   void handleElement(File xmlFile); //add anything else as needed
}

class NameHandler implements RequestedElementHandler {
  public String getHandledElementName() { return "name"; }

  public void handleElement(File xmlFile) {
    //write name to file
  }
}
```

And when handling your request:

```
Collection<String> requestedElements = ...;

//just an example, maintain a reusable map in a real world example
Map<String, RequestedElementHandler> handlers = new HashMap<>();

//you could use handlers.put("name", new NameHandler()) but doing it that way lets the handler define what elements it will work on
NameHandler nameHandler = new NameHandler();
handlers.put(nameHandler.getHandledElementName(), nameHandler());

//add other handlers as needed

for( String element : requestedElements ) {
   RequestedElementHandler handler = handlers.get(element);
   if( handler != null ) {
     handler.handle(xmlFile);
   }
}
```

**Update:**

Since your request body actually contains boolean properties you could modifiy the above approach as follows:

```
class NameHandler implements RequestedElementHandler {
  //rename in interface
  public String getPredicateName() { return "isNameRequired"; }
}
```

And when processing the request:

```
//extract the parameters from the request - how depends on whether you have 
// - a ServletRequest: getParameterMap()
// - a Json object: try Jackon's ObjectMapper.readTree() and extract property names and values from the generic json object you get
// - anything else: can't tell without knowing but you should be able to do some research
Map<String, Boolean> parameters = ...

for( Map.Entry<String, Boolean> parameterEntry : parameters.entrySet() ) {
  //reject FALSE and null
  if( !Boolean.TRUE.equals(parameterEntry.getValue()) {
    continue;
  }

  RequestedElementHandler handler = handlers.get(parameterEntry.getKey());
  //use handler
}
```

**Alternative:**

Maintain a list of `RequestHandler` elements which *all* get the request and act on it if needed.

Example:

```
interface RequestHandler {
  void handleRequest(Request r, File xmlFile);
}

class NameHandler implements RequestHandler {
  void handleRequest(Request r, File xmlFile) {
    if( !r.isNameRequired() ) {
      return; //request doesn't require the name so skip
    }

    //add name to xml file
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Request request = ... //your request object
File xmlFile = ... //the file you want to write to
List<RequestHandler> handlers = ... //get from somewhere
handlers.forEach(handler -> handler.handleRequest(request, xmlFile));
```

Comment: Thanks for time and effort, but this is not what I want exactly (or this is too high level for me to understand). I've updated the question, please consider that

Comment: @SivaRahul well, the approach would still work here but could be modified. Basically from what you're asking it looks like GraphML could be a match but if my suggestion is too high level already then GraphML might be too. Without knowing more of your code, e.g. what the requests look like etc., it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Updated the question with the request body, thanks @Thomas

Comment: @SivaRahul added 2 options - if those are still too complex then you might have to go for all those if-statements (still fine - it just may become hard to read and maintain if the list grows and adding new "handler methods" would require the list of statements to be altered as well).